# HTML file not loading js file (NodeJS + Express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am running a NodeJS server that serves static files in my public directory. However, my javascript file, main.js, does not run. Below is my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(3000);
```

main.js

```
function main() {
    console.log('test');
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

directory structure:

- app.js
- public

  - index.html
  - javascripts

    - main.js

Comment: can you add type="text/javascript" before src in your script statement

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` HTML5 wouldn't need that

Comment: please check path ...

Comment: just copied your code ... opened `http://localhost:3000/` and everything worked fine (`test` logged to console as expected) - you're missing something

Comment: 1: how are you running the node app? 2: anything show in the browser develoepr tools console that indicates an error? 3: what operating system are you using? 4: If Microsoft, have you allowed nodejs to act as a server in windows? (windows can be a bit funny about this)

Comment: Observe the network tab of your browser's developer tools and see what's the response code of requesting `main.js`.

Comment: @JaromandaX I just tried restarting my computer and it started working! hate when this happens, thanks tho!